# How do I remove a MATLAB program running on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: uninstall, matlab, rm

I have installed **MATLAB 2012** on Ubuntu 14.04, and I want to uninstall it. According to the support instructions, I should type in a command as `rm -rf matlabroot`. Howeever, this does not help. In fact, it does nothing.

What could be the problem? and how can I uninstall MATLAB.

Comment: Where have you installed the Matlab program? Could you please link us to the installation/uninstallation tutorial that you followed?

Comment: Have you tried - `sudo rm -rf matlabroot` ?

Comment: I was working as a super user because I worte " sudo -i " before

Comment: I have installed it in home/programs, the tutorial was a pdf attached with the CD

Comment: If it said nothing, it probably worked.

Comment: Then, `sudo rm -rf matlabroot` should remove it.

Comment: First `cd /home/<username>/programs`, then `sudo rm -rf matlabroot`

Answer (score 0):

**As the comments were getting long, thus this answer**

1. Goto to the folder where Matlab is installed:

**E.g.,** If your folder is in /home/abc/matlabroot, then goto /home/

**matlabroot is the name of the folder which you want to remove**

2. Open a terminal and type:

   `cd`
3. Then, drag the folder 'abc' into the terminal and drop it there.
4. Hit enter.
5. Now type:

   `sudo rm -rf matlabroot`